# How do I send a c# vCard to iOS?

Tags: c#, ios, vcf-vcard

I have a database application where I allow the user to download an individual from the database into their Outlook contacts.  The program sends a vCard to Outlook just fine on a Windows machine.  On iPad and iPhone email, it receives the vCard as text, not as a vCard attachment.

BEGIN:VCARD VERSION:4.0 N;LANGUAGE=en-us:Doe;John;;Mr. FN:Mr. John Doe TITLE: ORG: ADR;HOME;PREF;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:;; TEL;WORK;VOICE: TEL;HOME;VOICE: TEL;CELL;VOICE:(999) 555-1212 TEL;WORK;FAX: ADR;WORK;PREF;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:;;123 Main St New York New York 10000 EMAIL;PREF;INTERNET:johndoe@gmail.com EMAIL;INTERNET: URL;WORK: NOTE: END:VCARD

I wonder if I am not attaching the vCard to the mail message correctly or if I need to change how I convert my vCard string into an attachment for iOS.

My iPhone users are on iOS 7 & 8.

I've done a lot of research on this topic including http://mobicontact.info/iphone/ios7-supports-vcard-vcf-download-at-last/ but I haven't found an answers specific to my scenario.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("BEGIN:VCARD\r\n");
            sb.Append("VERSION:4.0\r\n");
            sb.AppendFormat("N;LANGUAGE=en-us:{0};{1};;{2};\r\n", member.LastName, member.FirstName, member.Prefix);
                sb.AppendFormat("FN:{0} {1} {2}\r\n", member.Prefix, member.FirstName, member.LastName);
                sb.AppendFormat("TITLE:{0}\r\n", member.Title);
                sb.AppendFormat("ADR;HOME;PREF;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:;;{0}\r\n", member.Address + " " + member.City + " " + member.City + " " + member.ZIP);
            sb.AppendFormat("TEL;WORK;VOICE:{0}\r\n", member.WorkPhone);
            sb.AppendFormat("TEL;HOME;VOICE:{0}\r\n", member.HomePhone);
            sb.AppendFormat("TEL;CELL;VOICE:{0}\r\n", member.CellPhone);
            sb.AppendFormat("TEL;WORK;FAX:{0}\r\n", member.Fax);                
            sb.AppendFormat("EMAIL;PREF;INTERNET:{0}\r\n", member.WorkEmail);
            sb.AppendFormat("EMAIL;INTERNET:{0}\r\n", member.HomeEmail);
            sb.AppendFormat("URL;WORK:{0}\r\n", member.Website);
            sb.AppendFormat("NOTE:{0}\r\n", member.Notes);
            sb.Append("END:VCARD\r\n");
            string cardContent = sb.ToString();

            byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(cardContent);

            //save the data to a memory stream
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data);


            Attachment newAttachment = new Attachment(ms, searchName.Name + ".vcf", "text/x-vcard");

            ContentDisposition disposition = newAttachment.ContentDisposition;

            disposition.CreationDate = DateTime.Now;
            disposition.ModificationDate = DateTime.Now;
            disposition.ReadDate = DateTime.Now;
            disposition.DispositionType = DispositionTypeNames.Inline;

            /Set up new email message
            MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();                
            mailMessage.Attachments.Add(newAttachment);   

            //Set up addresses
            mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(emailAddress);
            mailMessage.To.Add(emailAddress);

            //Set up subject and body
            mailMessage.Subject = "VCard: " + searchName.Name;
            mailMessage.Body = "Attached is a VCard from the festival database";

            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("cashub.palau.org");
            smtp.Send(mailMessage);
```